# Need a little help understanding range() and len()

Tags: python

Heres the code and output:

```
a = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0,-1):
    print(a[i])
```

Output:

```
3
2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Shouldn't we also get an output for "1" ? 
Does it ommit the last value like [x:y] does for y?

I apologise if this question was asked but I couldn't find anything related here or just by searching. 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You are printing `i` - the index, not the value at `a[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are trying to do is this:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(a)-1, 0,-1):
    print(a[i]) # Notice the change
```

Comment: Yes, my bad! I was trying to reduce my code to a minimal example. But after correcting it like above, I get 3 and 2. So its ommiting the a[0] = 1 now. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @Fl1pp `range` goes till you number in the second place, you can put `-1` insted of `0` if you want it to go thru all of them, if its the correct answr mark it so it will help pther people :)

Comment: Oh, it makes sense now. I was thinking that range() ommits the biggest value but its actually the LAST. 
Thanks for bothering to answer such a silly question. Cheers :)

Comment: @Fl1pp no problem :) always feel free to ask your question, also it will be nice if you can mark it as the correct answer so it will help others people